# Understanding Firebase storage when uploading files

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

If the user wants to upload 20 images together (one connection) to Firebase storage and during uploading failed when reaching image number 14 because there is no internet anymore so what will happen for the 13 images who uploaded already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Firebase API to upload multiple files to Cloud Storage in one go. So if you upload 20 files, that'll be 20 separate uploads. If you're using Firebase's upload session URIs to [continue uploads across restarts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#continuing_uploads_across_process_restarts), that will also apply to each individual file in this case.

If you want to upload multiple files atomically, consider combining them into a single (e.g. zip) file, and then using a Cloud Function trigger to unpack the individual files from that archive.